# Is there anyway to schedule the activation of a workflow?

Tags: workflow, schedule

I am the only salesforce admin at the company i work for. i have created some workflows that i do not wish to be activated until a certain time. unfortunately that time is when i am on holiday.

does anyone know if there would be a way of setting up another workflow or a schedule that will activate the workflow whilst i am away?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are ready for some coding then i guess your requirement can be fulfilled by use of Metadata API.You can activate and deactivate workflow with the help of Metadata API.

Plus you can create certain schedule which will call this activation code whenever you want.

for more information on use of Metadata API and apex wrappers visit this [link](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

Answer (score 0):

If it's not mandatory requirement to postpone activation. In you parcilar case you could postpone your workflow execution by adding date/time check:

```
and(Now() > DATETIMEVALUE("2016-04-28 09:00:00"), condition1 )
```

This simple workaround will allow to avoid coding, testing, deploying and maintaining of your code.

Comment: OP doesn't talk about workflow execution, its about activating workflows automatically.